# Has spring-eureka-common mvn dependency been replaced?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am new to Netflix Zuul and I am trying to build JwtConfig within my Zuul gateway by following an online tutorial. I have the below maven dependency, but cannot locate it on mvnrepository. Has it become deprecated or replaced by another dependency? If so, what dependency should I be using? I need it to use JwtConfig in one of my classes.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.eureka.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-eureka-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

My code:

```
import com.eureka.common.security.JwtConfig;
@Autowired
private JwtConfig jwtConfig;
```

Comment: Such dependency was never in Maven Central

Answer (score 4):

The dependency is created by author of tutorial.
The project source code of `spring-eureka-common` should be in the same repository.

Comment: https://github.com/OmarElGabry/microservices-spring-boot/blob/master/spring-eureka-common/src/main/java/com/eureka/common/security/JwtConfig.java